# How to create an application with python pyramid 1.2 version using anaconda prompt?

Tags: python, anaconda, pyramid

The steps i followed to create a new project :-
I created a new kernel using the command and installed python 3.5 version
`conda create -n pyramid_kernel python=3.5`
Then i activated the kernel
`conda activate pyramid_kernel`
Then in the directory that i want i navigated and created a virtual environment and installed pyramid version 1.2 there

```
py -m venv tutorial_env 
tutorial_env\Scripts\activate
py -m pip install "pyramid==1.2"
```

Then i tried creating a new project using

```
paster create -t pyramid_starter foo
```

But is shows some error :-
TypeError :- Class advice impossible in python3. Use @implementer class decorater instead

Comment: Python 3.5 and Pyramid 1.2 are both very old.  Why are you specifying those?

Comment: Its an older version. We have developed a project years ago in those version. In order, to upgrade that we need to get started with this version thats why.

Comment: Pyramid 1.2 does not run on Python 3. Pyramid 1.3 added support for Python 3.2. I would not run this in Conda as it is one more layer of complexity. Instead use pyenv for multiple Python versions, and create a virtual environment using the supported version of Python as you upgrade your Pyramid app stepwise. Good luck, you'll need it!

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out in comments, one needs Python 2.7. Additionally, since the versions are so old, and `pyramid==1.2` doesn't have upper bounds on its dependencies, the `zope` packages need to be pinned as well. The following YAML works for me:

**pyramid_kernel.yaml**

```yaml
name: pyramid_kernel
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python=2.7
  - pip
  - pip:
    - pyramid==1.2
    - zope.component==3.6
    - zope.interface==3.5.1
```

I can confirm at least that this enables `import pyramid` to work in the Python interpreter of the resulting environment.